# Count and enumerate LI's with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this Ul with some Li's that are generated by Wordpress.
If I use `<?php the_ID(); ?>` it gets all messed up, the posts id aren't in order.
What I need to do is to make jquery count and write number 1, 2, 3 and 4 in my humble list.
This is my Ul 
The loop will get 4 posts, therefore, 4 `<li>'s`

```
<div id="controle">  
    <ul>
<?php
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>

  <li>
<a href="<?php the_ID(); ?>">1 <--! see? here is where the count goes :D --> </a>
  </li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
        </div>
```

I thought something with

```
$('#controle li').each(function(e){

}
```

would do the trick, but not sure how to proceed on this :(

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your `each` loop, first argument of `each` callback is `index`

```js
$('#controle li a').each(function(index){
    $(this).prepend('<span class="myNumberClass">'+ (index+1) +'</span>')
})
```

Comment: with the a $('#controle li a').each(function(index) its perfect, thank you

Comment: can also do this very simply in php using an incrementing counter in `while` loop

Comment: This I tried but i believe WP loop wouldn't aloud. $i++ just didn't wordk

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( "#controle li" ).each(function( index ) {
  $(this).find("a").text(index + 1);
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KcfWL/)